Powershell add zeros to middle of string
I have a series of filenames as follows
1.2.2
1.2.3
1.2.4
1.10.1
1.10.2
I would like to convert them to the following format
1_002_002
1_002_003
1_002_004
1_010_001
1_010_002
So basically, I need the second and third digits to have three characters in each and the decimal replaced with an underscore.
Thanks in advance.
I think I need to split the string into three and add leading zeros but don't know how to do that in Powershell.

You can use regex replacement with a match evaluator, a.k.a. replacement with a scriptblock to replace every . followed by 1 or 2 numeric digits with an _ followed by those numeric digits with left padding using 0 as the padding character:

PowerShell 6+ Version:

$strings = @(
    '1.2.2'
    '1.2.3'
    '1.2.4'
    '1.10.1'
    '1.10.2'
)

$strings -replace '\.([0-9]{1,2})', { '_' + $_.Groups[1].Value.PadLeft(3, '0') }


PowerShell 5.1 Version:

$strings = @(
    '1.2.2'
    '1.2.3'
    '1.2.4'
    '1.10.1'
    '1.10.2'
)

$strings | ForEach-Object {
    [regex]::Replace($_, '\.([0-9]{1,2})',
        { '_' + $args[0].Groups[1].Value.PadLeft(3, '0') })
}

Both version outputs:
1_002_002
1_002_003
1_002_004
1_010_001
1_010_002


This version uses RegEx groups to break out the second and third numbers, convert them to integers, and then uses the format operator to properly format and join the parts.  It also reports text that fails to match, and works in PowerShell 5.1 and 7.x:
[String[]]$FileNames =
'Some File 1.2.2.Dat', 'Some File 1.2.3.Dat', 'Some File 1.2.4.Dat', 'Some File 1.10.1.Dat', 'Some File 1.10.2.Dat', 
'Failed match 1', 'Failed match 2',
'1.2.2', '1.2.3', '1.2.4', '1.10.1', '1.10.2'
$ConvertedFileNames = $FileNames | & {
   process {
      if ($_ -match '^(?<Before>.*\d+)\.(?<V2>\d+)\.(?<V3>\d+)(?<After>.*)$') {
         '{0}_{1:d3}_{2:d3}{3}' -f $Matches.Before, [int]$Matches.V2, [int]$Matches.V3, $Matches.After
      }
      else {
         Write-Warning "Failed to convert `"$_`""
      }
   }
}
$ConvertedFileNames

Using the above code produces this output:
WARNING: Failed to convert "Failed match 1"
WARNING: Failed to convert "Failed match 2"
Some File 1_002_002.Dat
Some File 1_002_003.Dat
Some File 1_002_004.Dat
Some File 1_010_001.Dat
Some File 1_010_002.Dat
1_002_002
1_002_003
1_002_004
1_010_001
1_010_002

